# Not able to persist to sql server database using persistence.xml

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to java. I am trying to connect my application to SQL server database on my machine but getting following error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Sub:     The following providers:
oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider
oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
Returned null to createEntityManagerFactory.
```

My persistence.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Application">
     <provider>
        oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>

    <class>com.application.entity.ProductEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url"value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Application"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="Infosys1"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    </properties>



</persistence-unit>
```

My service class is:

```
package com.application.service;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
     import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;

    import com.application.entity.ProductEntity;
    import com.application.to.productTo;

   public class ProductService 
     {

public int addProduct(productTo to)
{
    EntityManager em = null;
    ProductEntity product = new ProductEntity();
    try {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Sub");

        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
        et.begin();

        // Persist Product

        product.setProductName(to.getProductName());
        product.setBasePrice(to.getBasePrice());
        product.setSellingPrice(to.getSellingPrice());
        product.setQuantity(to.getQuantity());
        product.setCompany(to.getCompany());

        em.persist(product);
        et.commit();

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (em != null)
        {
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return product.getProductId();


    }
     }
```

I have included below jars in java build path and also in lib folder in webcontent:

1. sqljdbc4-2.0.jar
2. toplink-essentials-agent.jar
3. toplink-essentials.jar

My persistence.xml path is \Application\src\META-INF\persistence.xml

Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This issue doesn't have to do with the database, it likely has to do with JPA not finding your persistence.xml or the unit on the classpath.  The persistence.xml needs to be in a meta-inf directory at the root of the classes directory on the classpath.  If you think it is being found on the classpath, set TopLink logging property to FINEST so it will log issues:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/configure-logging-092723.html

Answer (score 0):

In `persistence.xml` among others, you should have something like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit">
```

When you're creating the `EntityManagerFactory` make sure to give the same name as defined in the file:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistenceUnit");
```

In your case you have `"Sub"` in code and `"Application"` in the file; the code wants to create one with the name `"Sub"` but that is not defined, hence the error message: `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Sub`.

Comment: I changed the persistence-unit name as "Sub" but getting the same error

Comment: Try adding `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` in the persistence-unit so it's `<persistence-unit name="Sub" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL>`

Comment: I tried as suggested by you. But getting same error.

Comment: Then you're either missing a dependency (I haven't work with TopLink) or the `persistence.xml` (or some jars) are not on the classpath; if you're using Maven, it should be in `resources` directory no directly under src.

Comment: Actually I am able to connect the database using following code: 
  
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress";      String user = "sa";
             String pass = "Infosys1";
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass); But unable to connect through the persistence.xml.  I am not using maven.